# Limiting Dropbox cache size

Tags: caching, dropbox

I am having an issue with the Dropbox cache, whereby periodically I find that a particular machine I am syncing to with Dropbox has run out of disk space and the Dropbox cache is the culprit.  This is a problem because the machine Dropbox is installed on is headless (or nearly so) and therefore the only indication that something is wrong is suddenly data that should be available on the machine isn't.

I have read that it is possible to clear the cache, but this is a pain as this machine is running OS X and there is no command line interface, meaning that I have to VNC into the machine simply to restart Dropbox.  This also seems to limit my options for automatically clearing the cache, although having to create a periodic task to clean the Dropbox folder seems kludgy and error prone.  (For instance, the disk could fill up before the script runs.)

(Update: It appears that deleting the files in a low disk condition results in Dropbox starting to sync again without restarting, but I am not sure if there are any undesirable side-effects to this, everywhere I have read about the cache says to stop Dropbox during the delete and restart it afterwards.)

In addition, it appears that the reason Dropbox is running out of space so fast is that I have a single large log file (on the order of half a gigabyte) which is append-only, but Dropbox is creating a new cached copy of the entire old version every time a change is made.  So from the standpoint of performance, it is kinda undesirable that it keep creating duplicates of this large file for every tiny addition of a few bytes to the file.

Disk space is rather tight on this machine, so I would rather simply have Dropbox limit how much caching it does.  Is there some way to do this?  My searches so far have turned up empty.

Update: I tried opening a Dropbox support request, only to get an e-mail reply stating: "Thanks for writing in. While we'd love to answer every question we get, we
unfortunately can't respond to your inquiry due to a large volume of support
requests." ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 1):

I just have a command file that I run now and then on my MacBook Air to clear space, which contains also these lines:

```
rm -rf /Users/MYUSERNAME/Dropbox/".dropbox.cache"/old_files/{*,.*}

osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to quit' & exit
```

Should be easy enough to automate, no?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with the exact same cause (took a while to figure out too): a log file inside a Dropbox folder that is actually not that big (several MB), but it does update every minute with a couple of hundred bytes.  My cache is killing me.  My total local Dropbox folder has 150 GB of which 50 GB is the cache!

I just cleared it, and my understanding is there are no consequences other than resync, but this is unsustainable.

I see several solutions here:

1. Dropbox is not suitable for this use case.  Do not keep frequently updated logs on Dropbox.  I think this would be a bummer, because there should be a fairly simple technical solution to this, and they are:
2. Dropbox either has OR SHOULD HAVE a setting for the maximum size of the cache, the way browsers do.  This should not be too hard to implement if it does not exist (apparently), otherwise tell us where it is.
3. A script can be written (talking about Linux here) that periodically (every hour should be enough, but it can be done every minute in theory) checks for disk size of .dropbox.cache and if it is over some limit, it will delete some files.  You could delete 10 most recent ones, or 10% of the files, or if you really wanted to go fancy you could calculate how much you have to delete, from oldest file on to maintain a certain cache size. The issue might be stopping Dropbox but seems like if you simply pause syncing that should be ok and enough.

Number 2 and #3 are really one and the same, it's just a question of who is going to do it.  Given that Dropbox isn't an open source platform, it would probably be best for Dropbox to write and maintain this feature.  Any third party plugin for this may stop working when something inside Dropbox codebase changes.

Dropbox does have an incentive NOT to provide this feature, because frequent syncing = more bandwidth.  But I thought we pay for bandwidth.

Thank you Dropbox, we all love you, especially since you gave us all that extra space for free.